# How to send mail using php by insert html into mail content?

Tags: php, html, email

How to send mail using php by insert html into mail content ?

I tried to insert html code inner `$message`, When i test it's show error

like this  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'margin' (T_STRING)`

How can i do ?

```
<?PHP
include("connect.php");
$email = "test_mail@hotmail.com";    
$to = $email;
$subject = "test subject";
$message = "

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy9QUm.jpg"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                test text
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: EXAMPLE <noreply@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Return-Path: return@example.com' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-freturn@example.com');
?>
```

Comment: surround your message with single quote instead of double quote

Comment: or escape them `\"string\"` - it's longer, but is valid syntax.

Comment: The answer given below, answers the question  for what you posted and should be marked as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue with wrapping your `$body` string try this

```
 <?PHP
    include("connect.php");
    $email = "test_mail@hotmail.com";    
    $to = $email;
    $subject = "test subject";
    $message = "

    <body style='margin: 0; padding: 0;'>
        <table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy9QUm.jpg'/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    test text
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>

    ";

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: EXAMPLE <noreply@example.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Return-Path: return@example.com' . "\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-freturn@example.com');
    ?>
```

Comment: I don't know why you went through all that trouble to change the quotes. All that was needed to do was `$message = '` and `';` - *Done like dinner* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- hahahahahaha indeed didn't notice!!!! +1

Comment: Oh well, it has been done ;-) *Cheers*