# How to send email include html code using php?

Tags: php, html, email

How to send email include html code using php ?

I tried to use this code.

```
<?PHP
    include("connect.php");
    $email = "test_mail@hotmail.com";    
    $to = $email;
    $subject = "test subject";
    $message = "

    <body style='margin: 0; padding: 0;'>
        <table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy9QUm.jpg'/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    test text
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>

    ";

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: EXAMPLE <noreply@example.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Return-Path: return@example.com' . "\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-freturn@example.com');
    ?>
```

When i open my email it's will show like this in my email.

```
<body style='margin: 0; padding: 0;'>
    <table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy9QUm.jpg'/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                test text
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

But i want to show like this

[image]

How can i do ?

........................................................................................................................................................

Comment: This is one of those cases where you really did not google for it.

Comment: Google PHPMailer... Honestly it will save you a lot of time and helps deal with a lot of other issues along the way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160320/how-to-send-html-table-in-email-body-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Consider using some built option like https://github.com/nette/mail. @Mayhen has a point

Comment: You should get into the habit of accepting answers given for your other questions which seem to contain valid answers.

Comment: This question being an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/35207640/ which the given answer was the right one to close it with but you kept your mouth shut about it.

Answer (score 0):

Reason being is, that you don't have `<!doctype html>` and `</html>` tags (and other tags) and your HTML isn't being rendered as proper/full HTML markup.

```
$message = "
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
  <body style='margin: 0; padding: 0;'>
    <table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy9QUm.jpg'/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                test text
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
";
```

- Which upon testing afterwards, was successful.

---

**Foonotes:** (edit)

Even though I placed an answer, I decided to close the question being an exact duplicate of their other question [How to send mail using php by insert html into mail content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35207640/) where they were also **nonrespondant** and the answer given in there, answered what they posted for code.